# Line chart is not showing the data on clicking the radio button

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas

I have created a line chart using chart.js and there is radio button as well, so it should show data according to the selected radio button.

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="lineChartCtrl as chart">
    <div>
        <input type="radio"  value="Month"  name="optionsRadios" ng-model="graph" ng-click="months()"> Month
    </div>
     <div>
        <input type="radio" checked= "true" value="Quarter"  name="optionsRadios" ng-model="graph" ng-click="quarters()" >Quarter
     </div>
    <canvas  linechart options="chart.lineOptions" data="chart.lineData" height="140" responsive=true >
     </canvas>
</div>
```

My controller code:

```
function lineChartCtrl($scope,$http,$state)
{
   this.lineOptions = {
        scaleShowGridLines : true,
        scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
        scaleGridLineWidth : 1,
        bezierCurve : true,
        bezierCurveTension : 0.4,
        pointDot : true,
        pointDotRadius : 4,
        pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,
        pointHitDetectionRadius : 20,
        datasetStroke : true,
        datasetStrokeWidth : 2,
        datasetFill : true
    };
    this.lineData = {
        labels: ["Q2-18","Q3-18","Q4-18","Q1-19"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Example dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.7)",
                pointColor: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: quarter_score
            },
        ]   
    };



    $scope.quarters = function(){
        this.lineData = {
            labels: ["Q2-18","Q3-18","Q4-18","Q1-19"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Quarter_Wise",
                    fillColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.7)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                    data: quarter_score
                },

            ]
        };
        this.lineOptions = {
            scaleShowGridLines : true,
            scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
            scaleGridLineWidth : 1,
            bezierCurve : true,
            bezierCurveTension : 0.4,
            pointDot : true,
            pointDotRadius : 4,
            pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,
            pointHitDetectionRadius : 20,
            datasetStroke : true,
            datasetStrokeWidth : 2,
            datasetFill : true
        };
    }
    $scope.months = function(){
        console.log("inside month");
        this.lineData = {
            labels: ["APR-18","MAY-18","JUN-18","JUL-18","AUG-18","SEP-18","OCT-18","NOV-18","DEC-18","JAN-19","FEB-19","MAR-19"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Month_Wise",
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                    data: month_score
                },

            ]
        };
        this.lineOptions = {
            scaleShowGridLines : true,
            scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
            scaleGridLineWidth : 1,
            bezierCurve : true,
            bezierCurveTension : 0.4,
            pointDot : true,
            pointDotRadius : 4,
            pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,
            pointHitDetectionRadius : 20,
            datasetStroke : true,
            datasetStrokeWidth : 2,
            datasetFill : true
        };
    }

}
```

So by default, it is showing the quarter wise graph which is fine, but when I am selecting the month-wise from the radio button the graph is not changing, and on selecting quarter-wise from the radio button it is not taking any values from inside the function, only default value is shown on the graph (which is defined above the functions)

So where I am doing wrong.Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try using arrow functions 
`(() => {})` instead of anonymous functions `function {}` or `.bind(this)` on anonymous functions. Maybe you access wrong `this` when calling it from inside an anonymous function.

You could also try updating the data directly on the `chart.js` object.